# Password textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, password

Заранее прошу извинения если эта тема  уже была кем-то затронута, но на просторах интернета ответ на свой вопрос я получить не смог. Вкратце у меня есть программа windows forms C# на них имеется 2 textbox они работают в роли passwordbox.Но прогать на WPF я не умею и не хочу.Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы при в воде определенных символов (например:1234(пароль)) и при нажатии на кнопку "Войти" происходил переход на другую форму. Сам переход не нужно объяснять, я его уже реализовал.Спасибо заранее !

Comment: А что не получается?

Comment: сделать так чтобы пр наборе пароля 1234 производилась проверка и если пароль правильный то по нажатию на кнопку ,,,,

Comment: string a = "1234";
            if (textBox1.Text == a)
            {

            }

Comment: так????????????????

Comment: сПАСИБО Я РЕШИЛ ПРОБЛЕМУ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.В свойствах textbox(на панели конструктор Form1(скорее всего)) textBox_TextChanged задайте имя функции и нажмите enter

2.В тело функции добавьте проверку на ваш пароль

```
if(textBox1.text == password) // password переменная типа string которая хранит пароль

//грузим форму 2(ту которую хотим загрузить)
```

UPD: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx документация